# how to set upload path in express4?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express

I want to make express serve files requested as `http://localhost/uploads/image.png` serve the files out of a dynamic directory (based on environment) `process.env.NODE_UPLOAD_DIR` which would be something like:

`/home/user/data/uploads` but the app is served out of `~/www/domain.com`.

Is this possible?

I tried this, but it just redirects to homepage in browser when I request it (its an angular app if that makes any difference):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(proces.env.NODE_UPLOAD_DIR, 'uploads')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the "uploads" portion in both the URI and the filesystem path, you need to use it as a prefix:

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(
  path.join(process.env.NODE_UPLOAD_DIR, 'uploads'))
);
```

Comment: That worked, not sure exactly what is going on here.

Comment: It's tricky to keep both the URI paths and the filesystem paths straight in your mind, but just remember that by default, `static` is only going to serve files **within** it's root and does not consider the filesystem root dir part of the path. It expects a direct img.jpg to be within the configured static dir, so if you add a prefix to the URL, you need it for the middleware as well.

Comment: Thanks. makes sense. I could have `/image.png` instead of `/uploads/images.png` which is what it was doing originally for me.